# How to adjust card height with Bootstrap in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to follow this template design:[Template](https://colorlib.com/etc/lf/Login_v1/index.html) and I seem to be having some issue regarding the card height and padding with my current login page. Here is the code:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="card row h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                @csrf
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" src="{{asset('svg/MegaDeskLogo.svg')}}" alt="logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h1>{{ __('Login') }}</h1>
                        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                            name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus> 
                          @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>
                                   {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                                </strong>
                            </span> 
                          @endif

                        <input id="password" placeholder="{{ __('Password') }}" type="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required> 
                          @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                              <strong>
                                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                              </strong>
                            </span> 
                          @endif

                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old( 'remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                            <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                               {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                          {{ __('Login') }}
                        </button> 
                         @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                           <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{route('password.request') }}">
                             {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                           </a> 
                         @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Currently it's looking like: [image: Current design]. I've tried reading several articles and reading the bootstrap documentation and still not able to find the answer. If anyone can offer any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're adding all the CSS and Javascript libraries and code you need for your card to look like the example, they are using more than just bootstrap.

**Their CSS block:**

[image]

**Their Script block looks like:**

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your info, I'm not using their same classes, I'm just using that as a model and try to make the same structure using only bootstrap. I've tried to use bootstrap's height class, but it's not seeming to work properly

Comment: Try removing the "row" class from the card, and then applying some padding-top and padding-bottom to the card div. Also, I personally always add a column div inside row divs, just to keep it consistent and also helps with the layout.

Comment: I added an id and just adjusted the padding, worked like a charm. I also followed your `row` removal which seemed to help. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped!